# Move flexbox items on a mobile screen navigation

Tags: html, css, sass, responsive-design

I'm currently doing a responsive landing page, that has a media query at a max-width of 320px to change for a mobile design.

I'm having some issues moving the menu icon, the close icon, and the checkbox to the right of the mobile navigation at the top. I have used flexbox justify-self and justify-content to try and move all of them but with no success. I would want to end up with something like you see on the following screenshot:
[How the mobile menu should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MnbZ.png)

Here is my code:

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

@font-face {
  font-family: "IBM Plex Mono Regular", monospace;
  src: url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=IBM+Plex+Mono&display=swap");
}

/*  IBM Plex sans REGULAR  */
@font-face {
  font-family: "IBM Plex Sans Regular", sans-serif;
  src: url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=IBM+Plex+Sans&display=swap");
}

/*  IBM Plex Mono MEDIUM  */
@font-face {
  font-family: "IBM Plex Mono Medium", monospace;
  src: url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=IBM+Plex+Mono:wght@500&display=swap");
}

/*  IBM Plex sans Semi Bold  */
@font-face {
  font-family: "IBM Plex Sans Semi Bold", sans-serif;
  src: url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=IBM+Plex+Sans:wght@600&display=swap");
}

/*TAMAÑOS*/
/*COLORES*/
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*normalizadores*/
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*BODY*/
body {
  max-width: 1440px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

/*HEADER con NAV y menu hamburguesa*/
.nav_mobile {
  display: none;
}

.nav_desktop {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.nav_desktop .container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

.nav_desktop .container .logo_desktop {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.nav_desktop .container .nav_list {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav_desktop .container .nav_list .nav_item {
  font-family: "IBM Plex Mono Regular", monospace;
  line-height: 28px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #060a24;
  padding-right: 28px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

/*Para version mobile*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .nav_desktop {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav_mobile {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
  }
  .nav_mobile .dropdown_menu {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
        -ms-flex-pack: justify;
            justify-content: space-between;
    height: 44px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .nav_mobile .dropdown_menu .logo_mobile {
    margin-left: 16px;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
  }
  .nav_mobile .dropdown_menu #checkbox {
    position: absolute;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    width: 40px;
    height: 32px;
  }
  .nav_mobile .dropdown_menu #checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ ul {
    height: 224px;
  }
  .nav_mobile .dropdown_menu #icon_menu {
    position: absolute;
  }
  .nav_mobile .dropdown_menu #icon_close {
    position: absolute;
  }
  .nav_mobile .dropdown_menu ul {
    background: #0000ec 100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute;
    top: 44px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .nav_mobile .dropdown_menu ul li {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    margin-left: 16px;
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  .nav_mobile .dropdown_menu ul li a {
    font-family: "IBM Plex Mono Regular", monospace;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 28px;
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  .nav_mobile .dropdown_menu ul li:first-child {
    margin-top: 16px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/styles.css" />
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e16c5e6974.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Landing Podcast</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav class="nav_desktop">
        <div class="container">
          <img src="./images/logo.svg" alt="Logo" class="logo_desktop" />
          <ul class="nav_list">
            <li class="nav_item"><a class="nav_item" href="#">EPISODIOS</a></li>
            <li class="nav_item"><a class="nav_item" href="#">NOSOTROS</a></li>
            <li class="nav_item">
              <a class="nav_item" href="#">ENTREVISTAS</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav_item"><a class="nav_item" href="#">TÓPICOS</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <nav class="nav_mobile">
        <div class="dropdown_menu">
          <img src="./images/logo.svg" alt="Logo" class="logo_mobile" />
          <i class="fas fa-bars" id="icon_menu"></i>
          <i class="fas fa-times" id="icon_close"></i>
          <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just taking a guess here that this is along the lines of what you're looking for. You can accomplish a dropdown menu in mobile view by using a little JavaScript. I took the liberty of getting rid of your checkbox and adding some JS to add functionality to your nav window. The issue you were having in the first place was not with flexbox but with your use of `position`. It might help to read up more on how to use `position`.

```js
const menu = document.getElementById('icon_menu');

// open nav
menu.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const ul = document.querySelector('.dropdown_menu ul');
  const close = document.getElementById('icon_close');
  ul.style.display = 'block';
  menu.style.display = 'none';
  close.style.display = 'block';
});

//close nav
const close = document.getElementById('icon_close');
close.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const ul = document.querySelector('.dropdown_menu ul');
  ul.style.display = 'none';
  menu.style.display = 'block';
  close.style.display = 'none';
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*BODY*/
body {
  max-width: 1440px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

/*HEADER con NAV y menu hamburguesa*/
.nav_mobile {
  display: none;
}

.nav_desktop {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.nav_desktop .container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

.nav_desktop .container .logo_desktop {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.nav_desktop .container .nav_list {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav_desktop .container .nav_list .nav_item {
  font-family: "IBM Plex Mono Regular", monospace;
  line-height: 28px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #060a24;
  padding-right: 28px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

/*Para version mobile*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .nav_desktop {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav_mobile {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
  }
  .nav_mobile .dropdown_menu {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
        -ms-flex-pack: justify;
            justify-content: space-between;
    height: 44px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .nav_mobile .dropdown_menu .logo_mobile {
    margin-left: 16px;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
  }
  .nav_mobile .dropdown_menu  {
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 32px;
  }
  .nav_mobile .dropdown_menu #checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ ul {
    height: 224px;
  }
  
  i[id='icon_menu']{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  i[id="icon_close"]{
    display: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }

  .nav_mobile .dropdown_menu ul {
    display: none;
    background: #0000ec 100%;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute;
    top: 44px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .nav_mobile .dropdown_menu ul li {
/*     position: relative; */
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    margin-left: 16px;
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  .nav_mobile .dropdown_menu ul li a {
    font-family: "IBM Plex Mono Regular", monospace;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 28px;
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  .nav_mobile .dropdown_menu ul li:first-child {
    margin-top: 16px;
  }
  
}
```

```html
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/styles.css" />
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e16c5e6974.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Landing Podcast</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav class="nav_desktop">
        <div class="container">
          <img src="./images/logo.svg" alt="Logo" class="logo_desktop" />
          <ul class="nav_list">
            <li class="nav_item"><a class="nav_item" href="#">EPISODIOS</a></li>
            <li class="nav_item"><a class="nav_item" href="#">NOSOTROS</a></li>
            <li class="nav_item">
              <a class="nav_item" href="#">ENTREVISTAS</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav_item"><a class="nav_item" href="#">TÓPICOS</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <nav class="nav_mobile">
        <div class="dropdown_menu">
          <img src="./images/logo.svg" alt="Logo" class="logo_mobile" />
          <i class="fas fa-bars" id="icon_menu"></i>
          <i class="fas fa-times" id="icon_close"></i>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </body>
```

Comment: Hello, I don't know javascript yet so I'm trying to make this with just CSS and HTML. However, I'm able to read what you did with JS, as far as I understand, when you click the menu logo the ul will be displayed as a block and the menu icon will disappear and the close icon will appear. I will definitely read more about the use of position since I'm still not fully understanding what you did, as far as I can see the only difference with mine would be the commented position: relative in the list items, are you able to explain a bit more what you did?. Thank you very much for your help!